# reflexive, symmetric, and transitive relations proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, ... , n\}$ where $n$ is a positive integer. Let $F$ be the set of all functions from $A$ to $A$. Let $R$ be the relation on $F$ defined by:

for all $g, f \in F, fRg$ if and only if $f(i) \lt= g(i)$ for some $i \in A.$ Let $I$<sub>A</sub> : $A \to A$ be the identity function on $A$ defined by $I$<sub>A</sub>$(x)$ = $x$ for all $x \in A$.

a) Is $R$ reflexive? symmetric? transitive? Prove your answers. 
b) How many elements $f \in F$ are there so that $I$<sub>A</sub>$Rf$? Explain. 
c) How many elements $f \in F$ are there so that $fRI$<sub>A</sub>? Explain.
d) How many elements of $f \in F$ are there so that $fRI$<sub>A</sub> and $f$ is onto? Explain.

**My attempt to answer:**

a)
 We know a relation $R$ is reflexive iff *for all $x\in A$, $xRx$*
 We know a relation $R$ is symmetric iff *for all $x1, x2\in A$, if $x1Rx2$ then $x2Rx1$*
 We know a relation $R$ is transitive iff *for all $x, y, z\in A$, if $xRy$ and $yRz$ then $xRz$*

Now, using these definitions, we should be able to answer a).

*$R$ is reflexive:*

Let $f\in F$.

Then $f(1)\leq f(1)$, so $fRf$.

---

If $n=1$ then $F$ contains exactly one element and it is obvious that in that case $R$ is symmetric and transitive. This as a consequence of the fact that it is reflexive. So let us assume that $n>1$ from here.

---

*$R$ is not symmetric:*

Let $f\in F$ be prescribed by $i\mapsto1$ and $g\in F$ by $i\mapsto2$.

Then $fRg$ but not $gRf$.

---

*$R$ is not transitive:*

Let $f,g,h\in F$ with $f(1)=f(2)=2$, $g(1)=2\wedge g(2)=1$ and $h(1)=h(2)=1$.

Then $fRg\wedge gRh$ but not $fRh$.

**Now b)**

We know that Identity function returns the same values as its parameter, right? So, if you pass f(1) = 2, then identity function of f I<sub>A</sub> (2) = 1

so the question is how many elements $f \in F$ are there so that $fRI$<sub>A</sub>? Since, the I<sub>A</sub> is defined as:

I<sub>A</sub>(x) = x, this means there are n number of elements?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Comment: @5xum I have edited it, I am trying to focus on part a) and need some hints.

Comment: @5xum what do you think about part b)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is the answer to my own question: 
$a) $

*$R$ is reflexive:*

Let $f\in F$.

Then $f(1)\leq f(1)$, so $fRf$.

---

If $n=1$ then $F$ contains exactly one element and it is obvious that in that case $R$ is symmetric and transitive. This as a consequence of the fact that it is reflexive. So let us assume that $n>1$ from here.

---

*$R$ is not symmetric:*

Let $f\in F$ be prescribed by $i\mapsto1$ and $g\in F$ by $i\mapsto2$.

Then $fRg$ but not $gRf$.

---

*$R$ is not transitive:*

Let $f,g,h\in F$ with $f(1)=f(2)=2$, $g(1)=2\wedge g(2)=1$ and $h(1)=h(2)=1$.

Then $fRg\wedge gRh$ but not $fRh$.

b) $n^n$
c) $n^n$
d) $n!$

Answer (score 1):

First of, reflexivity:

You wrote down the definition of reflexive, which is your starting point. **Now**, it's time to actually do some work.

You want to **prove or disprove** the statement:

> For all $f\in F: fRf$, (because the relation is defined on $F$)

- If you want to **prove** the statement, then by definition, you therefore want to show that for every function $f$, there exists some $i\in A$ for which $f(i)\leq f(i)$.
- If you want to **disprove** the statement, then you must prove the negation of the statement. The negation of the statement 
  $$\forall f\in F: \exists i\in A: f(i)\leq f(i)$$
  is the statement $$\exists f\in F:\forall i\in A: f(i)>f(i)$$

Now, do you want to prove or disprove the statement?

---

Now, on to symetric. If you want to **prove** the statement or **disprove** it? Do you think the relation **is** or **is not** symmetric?

Comment: Thanks @5xum, please see the answer I posted, and can you help with b)?

Comment: @Samim do not post answers to your own questions. Rather, edit your original question with what you did so far.

Comment: edited the question. Can you give me some hints on b) please?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Get your hands dirty by writing down some actual examples of functions; don't try to prove things just yet (we're just working on some intuition for now). For example, consider the following functions $f,g,h \in F$, where for concreteness I fix $n = 4$. Is $fRg$? Is $gRh$? Is $fRh$? Is $hRf$?

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
i & f(i) & g(i) & h(i) \\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
2 & 4 & 1 & 3 \\
3 & 4 & 3 & 1 \\
4 & 4 & 3 & 1
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Please see the answer I posted for a). Now, any hints for b)? @Adriano